# How to have text between two lines? (e.g. when describing domains in maths)

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing

I was unsure of how to best word this question but I simply want to know how to space lines in mathmode to look like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use a `cases` environment, supplied by [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  k_{i2} = \begin{cases}
    k'_{i2} & \text{if $\lvert \eta \rvert < 0.15 \times G_{\max}$} \\
    0       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it with a matrix for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    ki2:
    \begin{matrix}
        ki2 & if  & |\eta|<1.5\: x\: G_{max} \\
        0   &     & otherwise\\
    \end{matrix}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Text shouldn't be typed in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

Using `nccmath` with the command `\mrel` it is possible with some hacks to obtain your original picture. By changing the value or decreasing it `[2.5ex]`, the two lines come closer together.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document} 
$k_{i2}\colon \mrel{k'_{i2} \quad \text{ if $\lvert\eta\rvert<0.15 \times G_{\max}$}\\[2.5ex] \mkern-70mu 0 \quad\, \text{ otherwise}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]